# Health Report for Marriage in Turkey

Tags: turkey, weddings

I live in the Netherlands and plan to get married in Turkey later this year to my Turkish fiancee. To do this I need a health report. I cannot find any useful information about how to obtain this report. It doesn't seem to be possible to obtain the report in Turkey without being a Turkish resident. And I can find literally no information about obtaining this report in the Netherlands. Does anyone know how I can obtain one?

Comment: What leads you to the conclusion that it doesn't seem to be possible to get the report in Turkey unless you are a Turkish resident?  The present answer has contradicted that statement without any citation, so, in the absence of evidence on both sides, I'm not sure whether to vote the answer up or down.

Comment: Surely your Turkish fiancee can find out more information about this for you, or has a contact in Turkey who can get an answer from the (local) Turkish Marriage Bureau https://www.outlookturkey.com/all-you-need-to-know-about-marriage-bureaus-in-turkey/

Comment: @phoog Initially my fiancee asked the local authorities and they told her I would need to bring the health report with me to Turkey. After I told her I don't see how that's possible she went back and they're now saying it should be possible to get the report from a hospital in Turkey. She lives in a part of the country where they probably don't marry many foreigners so that's probably why they got it wrong initially. I was also basing my information on the various unofficial sites that try to explain the whole process but I can readily believe they got it wrong.

Comment: @Traveller see last reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And I can find literally no information about obtaining this report in the Netherlands

It must be done in Turkey, the [US embassy in Ankara](https://tr.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/child-family-matters/marriage/how-to-get-married/) states :

> A medical examination is mandatory in order to get married. Each party needs to undergo a medical examination. The examination may be performed in designated medical clinics determined by the Turkish of Marriage Bureaus. You will need to contact the marriage bureau of your choice for the addresses of these clinics. A report of medical examination includes applicant’s blood type and results of blood tests for HIV, Hepatitis B & C, and Syphilis and indicates that the applicant has no contagious diseases. Medical reports without the applicant’s photo and doctor’s stamp will not be accepted.

> It doesn't seem to be possible to obtain the report in Turkey without being a Turkish resident

Provided payment, you shouldn't have any issue getting it

Comment: I don't see anything suggesting explicitly that these examinations are available to nonresidents.  The asker of the question presumably has some reason for thinking that they are not, but not having said what it is, we of course can't address it one way or the other.  Still, in light of his presumably reasonable conclusion that they aren't available to nonresidents, I would expect an answer claiming that the conclusion is incorrect to explain why that is.

Comment: @phoog I can't see how a clinic would refuse to do blood work provided payment. Furthermore, I can see an [agency](https://istanbul-tourist-information.com/en/wedding-in-turkey/procedure/) that claims they can arrange the clinic appointment for it

Comment: @phoog this information seems to agree with the information my fiancee is now getting from the local authorities which isn't the same information she got earlier from them. So I believe it's correct